# azure artifact not showing Nuget from upstream organization feed source

Tags: nuget-package, azure-artifacts

i am having transitive dependency on a nuget package. this package is coming from another organization feed (which gets it from second/another organization feed)

Below is what it looks like.
I am not able to upgrade the version of package (higher version doesn't show in my feed on search)

**Question**: why package version 1.1 is not showing in my feed, and I am not able to add it (from Visual studio, when i try to upgrade package version)

My project Feed:

| package | visibility | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my.package (version 1.0) | local | orgFeed1 |

orgFeed1 Feed:

| package | visibility | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my.package (version 1.1) (selected as current) | local | orgFeed2 |
| my.package (version 1.0) | local | orgFeed2 |

orgFeed2 Feed:

| package | visibility | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my.package (version 1.1) (selected as current) | local | Nuget |
| my.package (version 1.0) | local | Nuget |

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please make sure the user you are using has been set the correct role (`Contributor` or `Owner`) to download/cache the upstream feeds packages to your current feed.

Secondly, you have to allow packages that have been fetched from a private repo to be fetched from a public repo. See [Allow external versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-behavior?view=azure-devops&tabs=nuget%2Cget#allow-external-versions) and [Configure upstream behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-behavior?view=azure-devops&tabs=nuget%2Cget) for details.

You can also call the REST API to [Set Upstreaming Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/set-upstreaming-behavior?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0). Bellow PowerShell snippet for your reference to allow a package to be fetched from a public repo:

```
$env:PATVAR = "PAT_HERE"
$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String(([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("username:$PatVar")))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $token"
}
$url = 
    "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{FeedName}/{Protocol}/packages/{PackageName}/upstreaming?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
$body = '{"versionsFromExternalUpstreams": "AllowExternalVersions"}'
    
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: HI,I am owner in my project feed. Do i need to be owner/contributor in organization feed also?

Comment: @user9297554 No, not needed, however you need to make sure your project feed has the permission to access the organization feed. When adding another organization feed as the upstream source, the feed locator should like this: `azure-feed://{org}/{project}/feed@View`. So, you need to check the view permission setting. See [Views permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#views-permissions)